# AngularJS controller does not print entries in Rails project

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create a project where i use AngularJS as my front end and a Rails backend. Essentially i am following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R96rw9vEtiQ. I have set up a rails project and also installed the appropriate gems as suggested in the links. 
The angular ng-model directive functions as expected in my project but when I use the ng-controller directive and specify the controller functionality in a .js.coffee file(or .coffee file) that does not somehow link to my erb template.

this is the result i am getting [this is what i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4BNi.jpg). The expected result please watch the video at 4.56 min

Index.html file

```
<h1>Raffle#index</h1>
   <div ng-controller="RaffleCtrl">
   <form>
   <input type="text" ng-model="newEntry.name"></input>
   </form>
   <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="entry in entries">
         {{entry.name}}
      <li>
   <ul>
  </div>
```

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
   <title>Raffler</title>
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all'%>
   <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

   <%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

raffle.js.coffee

```
# Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller       here.
# All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
# You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://coffeescript.org/
@RaffleCtrl = ($scope) ->
$scope.entries = [
    {name: "Larry"}
    {name: "Curly"}
    {name: "Moe"}
]
```

gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported   runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more:     https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
 # gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
gem 'angularjs-rails'

group :development, :test do
# Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a   debugger console
gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
# Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in    views
gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring'
```

end

Comment: what do you mean, does not link to your erb template? can you show some example of the expected and actual results to help clarify what is happening?

Comment: Hi i have edited the question above to show you the expected. what i am getting has also been shown. Awaiting any response.

Comment: you still aren't providing enough information to help debug your project.  clearly something in your code doesn't match exactly to the video you are trying to follow, but showing a screenshot without providing any code at all doesn't do anything to show what that might be.

Comment: ok so finally i have added the code which i feel is relevant.